# Dead letter exchange queue set up not functioning as expected

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, dead-letter

I have an queue that is bound to an exchange as follows:

```
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="${normal_exchange}">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="${normal_queue}" key="${routing_key}" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

To this queue I have bound a dead letter exchange as follows:

```
<rabbit:queue name="${normal_queue}" auto-delete="false" durable="true">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange" value="${dead_letter_exchange}"/>
        <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all" />
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

I have bound a dead letter queue to the dead letter exchange as follows:

```
<rabbit:direct-exchange name="${dead_letter_exchange}">
<rabbit:bindings>
    <rabbit:binding queue="${dead_letter_queue}" key="${routing_key}"/>
</rabbit:bindings>
```

And the dead letter queue has been declared in the following manner:

```
<rabbit:queue name="${dead_letter_queue}" auto-delete="false" durable="true">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all" />
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

But when I look up the`normal_queue` in its details only following paremeters show up:

```
Details

Parameters  
arguments:  
x-ha-policy:    all
durable:    true
```

Should the dead letter exchange be listed here? Does this mean that the dead letter exchange has not been set up correctly?

Comment: @Belzuk might be able to help you

Comment: Looks strange. Like your `normal_queue` and `dead_letter_queue` properties have the same value...